# Cannot format NdefFormatable NFC tag

Tags: android, format, nfc, mifare, ndef

I'm developing an Android application that's using NFC. I have some NFC card with the following tech-list:

- android.nfc.tech.NfcA
- android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic
- android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable

But I cannot format those tags using `NdefFormatable.format(message)`. Instead, I get an IOException.

The code:

```
try {
    NdefRecord[] records1 = { createRecord("000000") };
    NdefMessage message1 = new NdefMessage(records1);
    formatable.format(message1);
    res = 1;
}
```

The stacktrace gave these logs:

```
W/System.err: java.io.IOException
W/System.err:     at android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable.format(NdefFormatable.java:131)
W/System.err:     at android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable.format(NdefFormatable.java:94)
                  at com.example.peng.nfcreadwrite.MainActivity.write(MainActivity.java:170)
W/System.err:     at com.example.peng.nfcreadwrite.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:27)
                  at com.example.peng.nfcreadwrite.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:60)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6877)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12651)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26069)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Maybe someone can give me something to look into, cause I'm fairly new into NFC on Android.

#### Edit

This is the screenshot I took using Mifare Classic Tool. It shows for sectors 4 to 8 that "no keys found(or dead sector)":

[image]

Comment: Was the tag used for something else before? Could it be that some of the sectors of the MIFARE Classic card are locked with some key other than the transport key? You might want to try to read the tag with some generic tag reader app (such as my NFC TagInfo or NXP TagInfo) to verify that all sectors are writable with transport keys.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply,
These cards were provided by some third party vendor my workplace used, they said it's a blank card. I have checked using the Mifare Classic Tool, and found out that all of the cards had sector 4 to 8 shown message No keys found(or dead sector). (please see my updated question for screenshot of the card I checked)

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same problem and posted a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61784673/how-to-erase-and-format-nfc-tag?noredirect=1#comment109286550_61784673
Can you share a full solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NDEF formatting procedure for MIFARE Classic tags on Android expects the tags to be empty and accessible (read & write) with the default transport key (`FFFFFFFFFFFF`) or certain standard keys (MAD key for sector 0, NDEF key for other sectors). If some sectors of the tag are inaccessible, Android won't be able to format the tag for use with NDEF.

Consequently, your tags are unusable for your purpose. Though you might be able to manually format the tag to skip those locked sectors. I'm not quite sure if Android is capable of using these tags then.

Comment: Your answer convinced me on my own suggestion. That the tags have some keys to access those sectors. I don't have the keys, so I can't read/rewrite them. After I bought some blank tags, I can write into them smoothly using my code, thank you @MichaelRoland for giving me some revelations.

Answer (score 0):

You can read and write Mifare Classic using the below codes

```
 @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction()) || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction()) || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {

        myTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        //  Toast.makeText(this, "MyTag :"+myTag, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      
        byte[] tagId = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID);
        Toast.makeText(this, "this is Tagid:" + tagId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        NfcSn = Hex.bytesToStringLowercase( tagId );
        System.out.println( "Tag Id"+NfcSn);


        MifareClassic mif = MifareClassic.get(myTag);
        //here is how to authenticate 

        try {
            mif.connect();
            if (mif.isConnected()) {
                boolean isAuthenticated = false;
                if (mif.authenticateSectorWithKeyA(1, MifareClassic.KEY_MIFARE_APPLICATION_DIRECTORY)) {
                    isAuthenticated = true;
                } else if (mif.authenticateSectorWithKeyA(1, MifareClassic.KEY_DEFAULT)) {
                    isAuthenticated = true;
                } else if (mif.authenticateSectorWithKeyA(1, MifareClassic.KEY_NFC_FORUM)) {
                    isAuthenticated = true;
                } else {
                    int block_index = mif.sectorToBlock(1);
                    byte[] block = mif.readBlock(block_index);
                    String s_block = Hex.bytesToStringLowercase( block );
                    System.out.println(s_block);
                }

                int block_index = mif.sectorToBlock(1);
                //here is how to read

                byte[] block = mif.readBlock(block_index);

                String s_block = Hex.bytesToStringLowercase( block );
                byte[] stringByte = hexStringToByteArray(s_block);
                String data = new String(stringByte,"UTF-8");

                System.out.println(data);
                System.out.println(s_block);
             
                System.out.println("is auth :"+isAuthenticated);
                //here is how to write
                mif.writeBlock(mif.sectorToBlock(1), new byte[]{'H', 'a', 'f', 'i', 'z', ' ', 'D', 'a', 'n', 'm', 'a', 'n', 'u', ' ', ' ', ' '});
                mif.close();
           }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


   

    setIntent(intent);
  

}

 public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
     int len = s.length();
     byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
     for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
         data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                 + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
     }
     return data;
 }
```